# browser.tabs is undefined in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Here is my `manifest.json` file:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "blocker.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "options_ui": {
    "page": "background-page.html",
    "browser_style": true
  }
}
```

and my `blocker.js` file:

```javascript
function cleanPage(tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) {
  console.log("I am in cleanPage");
}

try {
  console.log("browser : ");
  console.log(browser);
  console.log("browser.tabs : " + browser.tabs);

  browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(cleanPage);

} catch(err) {
  console.log("err : ", err);
}
```

And I get this error:

```
browser.tabs : undefined blocker.js:114:3
err :  TypeError: "browser.tabs is undefined"
```

My setup:
 - Mozilla Firefox 65.0.1
 - Ubuntu 18.04

I don't really understand this error, since I'm doing exactly what is written in the [Mozilla Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated#Syntax). Does anyone know why this error does appear?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My `blocker.js` file was in the `content_scripts`. I moved it to the `background_scripts` and it worked.

Only the files from the `background_scripts` can access the `browser.tabs` API.

My new `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": []
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "background.js", "blocker.js"]
  },

  "options_ui": {
    "page": "background-page.html",
    "browser_style": true
  }
}
```